Why My Spring Boot Application is not available in tomcat server
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.1</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cicd</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
       <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
       <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
       <connection/>
       <developerConnection/>
       <tag/>
       <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
       <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

this is my main class
package com.cicd.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

This is my rest controller class:
`package com.cicd.demo.controller;
package com.cicd.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class homeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

After building it creates \target\demo.war file
I have added this file to my webapps folder in tomcat server. But the http://localhost:8080/demo/ do not work. can anyone help me. It's totally new to me.
How can I fix this issue.

Which tomcat server? also why is spring-boot-maven-plugin a dependency?

check your tomcat log

Code looks fine. What do your Tomcat logs contain after you drop the war file? Does the war file get expanded into a folder called demo in the webapps folder. Is your %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/server.xml/Service/Engine/Host.unpackWARs set to true?

You should read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/deployment/traditional-deployment.html

Yes, the problem got solved when I used Tomcat version 10. Thank you all.
